# HTML in Ajax data vs. HTML inserted at render?

Tags: html, json, datatables, datatables-1.10

I have a dataset that's about 1000 rows x 6 columns. The HTML (mainly links) to go around each string (in cell) depends on its value. My target audience is in Bangladesh, so think slower connections and older browsers.

Would it load faster with the HTML in the actual data, or to have the javascript add it when rendering? I'm not sure what's worse, larger JSON with HTML to download, or more processing client-side but smaller JSON download.

Thanks!

Comment: Something to consider is that if you return HTML in the json, then the datatable sorting may not work as expected.

Comment: Hi Mark, that's a good point. Only one of my columns is searchable, though, so I'm mainly concerned with the other 5 columns.

Comment: Maybe the best thing to do is test it. With that amount of data you might not see a difference in performance.  Personally I think that a smaller data retrieval is always preferable especially if internet speed may be an issue, and datatables is designed to use client-side processing so handles this sort of thing with ease.

Comment: Thanks, Mark. I tried it out and you were right--smaller download with more client-side processing is the winner,